# serving both Vaadin and JSPs from the same webapp

Tags: jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, vaadin

I cannot get both my Vaadin app and some jsps using springmvc to work in the same webapp. The most promising approach seems to be doing the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fluxtream</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/main/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fluxtream</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

i.e. not serving the Vaadin app from the root of the webapp, but that gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPushServlet.service(ICEPushServlet.java:52)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

... which might be related to the fact that I'm using IcePush (a required dependency for me).

Anyhow, I would be grateful if someone could share their experience with serving an app alongside some jsps and springmvc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [this](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/112060) thread from Vaadin forums. Combine the discussed solution so that you have:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationRunner</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationRunnerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationRunner</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Microblog</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/MicroblogApplicationServlet/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This is an example for icepush Microblog portlet. Other Vaadin portlets or icepush portlets can be with their own url patterns. Consult the tutorial for Spring integration, how it links with this.

Comment: @user592699 Could you please tell, did these guidelines help you? Mark as accepted answer or tell the community somehow that other answer is waited..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception already the initialization of the servlet fails.

There might be some problem how the ICEPush add-on is configured. In your configuration there is no mention about the servlet at all. Vaadin application requires a servlet class to be configured and the ICEPush add-on uses it's servlet class. Take a look at the instructions at http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/icepush

Then you have to make sure that your URL patterns don't overlap with each other. I think that *.do and /main/ might do exactly that.